# How can I check if a web element exists in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to create a Java method which can check if an actual Selenium webelement exists.

It's important that I need to create a method, which would get a Webelement as a parameter, not a *By* or *String* id. And I want to avoid a try-catch solution, which would return a false if a NoSuchElementException would occur.

```java
public boolean isElementExists(WebElement element) {
    // TODO Implement...
}
```

Example:

#### File *foo.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button id="button1" type="button">First button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

#### File *FooPage.java*

```java
public class FooPage {

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "button1")
    public WebElement fistButton;

    //Missing button
    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "button2")
    public WebElement secondButton;
}
```

#### File *FooPageTest.java*

```java
public class FooPageTest {
    public void test(FooPage page) {
        page.firstButton.click(); // OK
        page.secondButton.click(); // NoSuchElementException
        // So I need to check if element exists in this class.
        // I can access here to the FooPage, the webelement to check, and to the driver.
    }
}
```

Comment: As per my knowledge your approach does not work, because the moment you hit `WebElement element=driver.findElement(XXX)` line selenium will try to return the element which does not exist on the page. So you will get `NoSuchElement` exception before hitting `isElementExists` method if element not exist on the page.

Comment: If still you want to stick to your idea, then you can take this approach - using `findElements` and then send that as param to `isElementExists(listofEelement, indexOfInteresedElement)` method.

Comment: Well the problem is, I got a big UI test system, which I have to fix at a lot of point. And there are already Page objects, which have WebElement properties. These properties are used at least a 1000 places and there are no checks if these exist. I want to create a Util class, which would have this method, and I would call it. But most of the places, I don't have an ID, or any information about the element's properties, just the WebElement and Page objects, and I have to deal with it somehow. So probably I could not use findElements in these circumstances.

Comment: You might be better off creating a custom implementation of the WebElement interface that wraps another WebElement in order to catch the NoSuchElementException that gets thrown when an element doesn't exist. Are you sure you aren't looking for something to test if an element is something you can interact with? That's an entirely different problem to solve.

Comment: Well maybe. So the actual system does not check if an element exists so it just try to e.g. click on non existing buttons and send text to non existing input elements. In this prespective, I can say I can't interact with them, but if you mean, the elements exist, it is just disabled or anything, then no, it's not what I'm looking for. Does it make sense? I try to write here an example soon.

Comment: Added some example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Selenium throws a NoSuchElementException when attempting to click on the second button, create a method in your page object that does the clicking:

```java
public class FooPage {
    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "button1")
    public WebElement firstButton;

    //Missing button
    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "button2")
    public WebElement secondButton;

    public FooPage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void clickThebuttons() {
        firstButton.click();

        try {
            secondButton.click();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            // Do something when the second button does not exist
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how much the try-catch solution would make slower the processes? If I would have to click for example about a 200 times in a test case?

Comment: @pityo10000: I doubt the difference will be noticeable. It's usually the `catch`/exception stack-unwinding part of a `try-catch` that is slower, and even then you need to benchmark the performance to know if the difference in speed in _actually_ a problem.

Comment: Ok, then probably, I'll use this solution. It seems there is no other way (which would be beautiful). Thank you very much!